# Why does the following hold when dealing with convergence in probability

Tags: convergence-divergence

The following text is from my textbook that I have a hard time understanding.

Let $X_1, X_2,X_3,...$ be independent random viariables such that

$P(X_n =1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} $ and $P(X_n = n) = \frac{1}{n}, 2 \leq n$

Clearly,

$P(|X_n -1| > \epsilon) = P(X_n = n) = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as n $\to \infty$

That is $X_n \to 1 $ as $ n \to \infty$ in probability.

My question is why does the following hold?

$P(|X_n -1| > \epsilon) = P(X_n = n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|X_n-1|> \epsilon$ then  $X_n \neq 1$ so $X_n =n$. If $X_n=n$ then $|X_n-1|=n-1>\epsilon$ provided $n >1+\epsilon$. So $P\{|X_n-1|> \epsilon\}=P\{X_n=n\}$ provided  $n >1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Is this because since, $P(X_n =1) + P(X_n = n) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} = 1$ Then $X_n$ can only be 1 or n? And if $X_n$ isn't 1 then it must be n?

Comment: You are right. That is precisely the argument.